# replacing roof screw

Tags: roof, metal

My Metal roof is 20 years old and a roofer told me to replace the screws with a bigger size. how do I determine my screw size? roof screws seem to have their own standards #10, #12, #14, #16... what does these numbers mean?

Answer (score 2):

The #10, #12 type numbers refer to the diameter of the screw. Larger numbers are bigger/thicker screw. Screws are sized by this diameter designation and also a length.

You could take one or two out temporarily and carry them with you when you go to the store to buy the new screws. You can then easily compare to the new ones to find the correct size.